# Parse json from internal resource file

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am beginner, trying to parse this json from a resource file, but no success. I can read the json but not parse it.

My json:

```
{"kind": "response",
 "columns": [
  "name",
  "kml_4326"
 ],
 "rows": [
  [
   "Spain",
   {
    "geometry": {
     "type": "Polygon",
     "coordinates": [
      [
       [
        61.211,
        35.65,
        0.0
       ],
       [
        62.231,
        35.271,
        0.0
       ],
       [
        62.985,
        35.404,
        0.0
       ]... etc...
```

My code:

```
try {

InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.bb);
Writer writer = new StringWriter();
char[] buffer = new char[1024];
try {
    Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
    int n;
    while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
} finally {
    is.close();
}

try {
    JSONObject aJson = new JSONObject(writer.toString());
    JSONArray json = aJson.getJSONArray("rows");
    for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = json.getJSONObject(i); // problem is here
        JSONObject bJson = new JSONObject(object.toString());
        JSONArray cJson = new JSONArray(bJson);
        JSONObject object1 = cJson.getJSONObject(1);
        JSONArray geometry = object1.getJSONArray("geometry");
    } 

}
catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

// The error: JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

```
org.json.JSONException: Value ["Spain",{"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[61.211,35.65,0],[62.231,35.271,0],[62.985,35.404,0],[63.194,35.857,0],[63.983,36.008,0],[64.546,36.312,0],[64.746,37.112,0],[65.589,37.305,0],[65.746,37.661,0],[66.217,37.394,0],[66.519,37.363,0],[67.076,37.356,0],[67.83,37.145,0],[68.136,37.023,0],[68.859,37.344,0],[69.196,37.151,0],[69.519,37.609,0],[70.117,37.588,0],[70.271,37.735,0],[70.376,38.138,0],[70.807,38.486,0],[71.348,38.259,0],[71.239,37.953,0],[71.542,37.906,0],[71.449,37.066,0],[71.845,36.738,0],[72.193,36.948,0],[72.637,37.048,0],[73.26,37.495,0],[73.949,37.422,0],[74.98,37.42,0],[75.158,37.133,0],[74.576,37.021,0],[74.068,36.836,0],[72.92,36.72,0],[71.846,36.51,0],[71.262,36.074,0],[71.499,35.651,0],[71.613,35.153,0],[71.115,34.733,0],[71.157,34.349,0],[70.882,33.989,0],[69.931,34.02,0],[70.324,33.359,0],[69.687,33.105,0],[69.263,32.502,0],[69.318,31.901,0],[68.927,31.62,0],[68.557,31.713,0],[67.793,31.583,0],[67.683,31.303,0],[66.939,31.305,0],[66.381,30.739,0],[66.346,29.888,0],[65.047,29.472,0],[64.35,29.56,0],[64.148,29.341,0],[63.55,29.468,0],[62.55,29.319,0],[60.874,29.829,0],[61.781,30.736,0],[61.699,31.38,0],[60.942,31.548,0],[60.864,32.183,0],[60.536,32.981,0],[60.964,33.529,0],[60.528,33.676,0],[60.803,34.404,0],[61.211,35.65,0]]]}}] at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:525)
```

I want to parse this JSON array. How can I do this?

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Finally, the goal is to access coordinates

Answer (score 0):

That is some awful JSON, do you have any control of it? The problem you have arrays within arrays within arrays. Specifically your error is because "rows" is an array of arrays so you need to have an inner loop.

```
    JSONObject aJson = new JSONObject(writer.toString());
    JSONArray rowsArray = aJson.getJSONArray("rows");
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = rowsArray.getJSONArray(i);
        for(int x = 0; x < jsonArray.length(); x++){
            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x); // now it will be the entry for spain
            JSONArray geometry = object.getJSONArray("geometry");
        }

    }
```

Coordinates is even worse because you have an array of arrays of arrays so it will require numerous loops.

Comment: Thank Notlineous, but still an error at : JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x); 
org.json.JSONException: Value Spain at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: yes I see that now, it really should be spain: {[ I dont know why that comma is there. Again if you have any control of how the JSOn is returned I would start there because this is terrible.

Comment: yes I have absolute control on the file. But another thing is that in the real file, there are countries with only one set of coordinates and others with several sets of coordinates.

Comment: not saying you cant have arrays but when they are being nested 2-3 deep you are going to have errors. Multiple sets of coordinates of what? what does each represent? Who knows, you are relying on indexes instead of identities. ["Spain": {"geometry" : "blah", "coordinates": [{"location name": "foo", "x" : 500, "y": 200,  "z": 0}, {}, {}]}, "other stuff": ""stuff]

Comment: the coordinates are latitude and longitude of the border of each country (in the real file Spain is ionly a part of the file)
Multiple sets of coordinates of what? : for example indonesia -> several islans belonging to one country so each island has its own set of coordinates

Comment: Code in javascript parsing that file
var rows = data['rows'];
        for (var i in rows) {
            var newCoordinates = [];
            var geometries = rows[i][1]['geometries'];
            if (geometries) {
              for (var j in geometries) {
                newCoordinates.push(constructNewCoordinates(geometries[j])); //  several sets of coord
              }
            } else {
              newCoordinates = constructNewCoordinates(rows[i][1]['geometry']); // if only one set 
            } 
        }
        constructNewCoordinates -> function for coordinates